# Best method for rescaling weights

Tags: r, weighted-regression

I'm investigating the effect of overhead cover (tree canopy) on the proportion of birds (in relation to mammals) scavenging on carcasses left out in nature. For this study I placed 35 carcasses in nature and measured the number of animals scavenging and the canopy cover.

The number of animals scavenging differs considerably amongst carcasses, ranging from 7 to 574. This number will be included in the analysis as weight. However, I want to rescale them in order to mitigate their effect.

There are many options to rescale weights, such as dividing everything by the maximum number of animals

```r
df <- mutate(df, Scaled_Weight = NumberOfAnimals / max(NumberOfAnimals)
```

Or by taking the natural logarithm

```r
df <- mutate(df, Scaled_Weight = log(NumberOfAnimals))
```

Or using an r function to do so

```r
df$Scaled_Weight <- scales::rescale(df$NumberOfAnimals, to = c(0.001,1))
```

Somebody told me that taking the square root is also a common practise for rescaling weights.

```r
df <- mutate(df, Scaled_Weight = sqrt(NumberOfAnimals))
```

Is there one method more applicable than the other? On what does it depend which method is most suitable? Which one is best for my particular case?

Comment: None of these approaches look appropriate.  Have you considered using a Binomial Generalized Linear Model?

Comment: Yes, but since I'm analysing continuous proportional data a binomial model is not appropriate, right? I'm using a ```glmmTMB``` with beta family: ```glmmTMB(ProportionBirdsScavenging ~ OverheadCover + (1|Area), data = df, beta_family(link = "logit"), weights = Scaled_Weight)```

Comment: These are *count* data: counts are about as discontinuous as one can get.  You created the need for weights by converting your raw data into proportions, so you can solve the problem by analyzing the data directly, thereby avoiding any need for weights at all.  That's one of the points of a GLM.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on that. So by simply changing my analysis family to bionomial and altering my response to absolute numbers ```glmmTMB(cbind(Birds, Mammals) ~ OverheadCover + (1|Area) , data = df,  family = binomial)``` would solve the problem of rescaling my weights, therefore increasing the reliability of my results?

Comment: That ought to work.  There may be an issue with "overdispersion," but that's a different matter altogether.

Comment: One assumption for using a binomial model is that the data is independent. In my case it's whether or not the probability of a bird scavenging affects the probability of a mammal scavenging, right? Does that mean that with a significant p value from ```tbl <- cbind(df_prop_birds_eating$Birds, df_prop_birds_eating$Mammals)
chisq.test(tbl, simulate.p.value = TRUE)``` the amount of birds is dependent on the amount of mammals, hereby making it impossible for me to use a binomial model?

Comment: I don't think you need to make such a stringent assumption. This is a probability model--so it makes no assumptions about mechanisms--and only states (for each carcass) that *conditional on the total number of scavengers, the number of birds has a Binomial distribution.* That can occur even when the actions taken by individual birds and mammals are interdependent. (It would fail most dramatically when the presence of one group scares away the other: that leads to "overdispersion.") You could fit this model and follow it with a goodness of fit test to assess how well the model fits the data.